# Recursive digital root algorithm

Tags: r

I am receiving the error

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Checking around I saw it means the condition is returning `NULL`, but I can't understand why and how to fix it.

```
digital_root = function(n){
  res=c()
  nc=nchar(n)
  for (t in 0:nc){
    esaminato = as.integer(n/(10^t))
    res=c(esaminato,res)
  }
  resFin = sum(res)
  nc = nchar(resFin)
  if (nc>1){
    digital_root(resFin)
  }
  else{
    return(resFin)
  }
}
print(digital_root(65))
print(digital_root(195))
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This error is thrown by `if` if the condition does not evaluate to TRUE or FALSE. So, `nc>1` evaluates to `NA`. Find out why it does that. I believe the condition should actually be `nc>2` but I can't be sure without knowing what exactly you intend.

Comment: I believe there is mistake in your algorithm: As part of your digital sum algorithm, you sum every digit of a number `n`. That's not what you're doing in the `for` loop. For example for `n=65`, in the first iteration your `res` after the `for` loop is `c(0, 6, 65)` which you then sum in `resFin`. Instead it should `sum(c(6, 5))`.

Comment: The error itself seems to stem from an integer overflow. For example, insert `tst<<-res` just before `resFin = sum(res)` then run `digital_root(65)`. When it crashes, check `tst`. Looks fine. Now try and sum it. `Warning message: In sum(tst) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))`

Comment: @Lyngbakr could `round()` be used in place of `as.integer` - round doesn't appear to have the same issues with larger numbers that as.integer does

Comment: Using `browser` like `digital_root = function(n){ browser() .... }`, The errro generated when `nc` reach 10 res become `[1]         0         2        23       236      2368     23685    236851   2368517  23685173
[10] 236851735        NA`. So resFin = sum(res) become na and 
  nc = nchar(resFin) become na. I don't understand why but I hope this been heplful for you.

Comment: @user5783745 That still causes my session to crash. This could be explained by the logic flaw that Maurits Evers identified.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that there is mistake in your algorithm when summing the digits of `n`. For example, for `n=65`, you are calculating `0+6+65` instead of `6+5`.**

Fixing that error, a slightly shorter version of your recursive digital root function would be

```
digital_root <- function(n) {
    res <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(n), ""))))
    if (nchar(res) > 1) digital_root(res) else return(res)
}
digital_root(65)
#[1] 2
digital_root(195)
#[1] 6
```

And for the Wikipedia example mentioned by @Roland in a comment below

```
digital_root(65536)
#[1] 7
```

We can also plot the digital root of the first 50 integers (reproducing [the plot on Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitalRoot.html))

```
# Vectorize digital_root to take a vector of integers as argument
dr <- function(n) Vectorize(digital_root)(n)
n <- 1:50
ggplot(data.frame(n = n, dr = dr(n)), aes(n, dr)) + geom_step(direction = "vh")
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, my code is wrong. The easiest way to amke it right would be to use `strsplit`, which you already are doing. I will delete my answer.